# Como tirar readonly de input

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estou tentando fazer com que ao clicar no `button` `btnEditar` libere os `inputs`: `funcionário`, `rca` e `regiao`... usei esse script porém não funcionou:

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
 $('document').on('click','#btnEditar', function(){ $(input[name="funcionario"]).removeAttr('readyonly'); $(input[name="rca"]).removeAttr('readyonly'); $(input[name="regiao"]).removeAttr('readyonly'); });
</script>
```

Esses são os inputs e o `button`:

```
<div class='form-group'>
    <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
        <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Funcionário</label></center>
        <input type='text' name='funcionario' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['funcionario']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
    </div>
</div>

<div class='form-group'>
    <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
        <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>RCA</label></center>
        <input type='text' name='rca' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['rca']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
    </div>
</div

<div class='form-group'>
    <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
        <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Região</label></center>
        <input type='text' name='regiao' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['regiao']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
    </div>
</div

<div class='form-group'>
    <div class='col-xs-6'>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block' role='button' id='btnEditar'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>&nbsp;Editar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Eu clico e não faz nada. Esse formulário está em um modal, se essa informação for importante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema parece-me porque você está a utilizar jquery antes de ele estar definido, passe as suas tags javascript para o fundo da pagina depois do include da libraria do jquery

Comment: isso mesmo, valeu cara

Answer (score 5):

Apenas corrija o seu seletor colocando aspas simples em volta `input[name="funcionario]"` e depois corrija o `readyonly` o correto é `readonly` de read = ler e only = apenas.

```js
$("#btnEditar").on('click', function() {
  $('input[name="funcionario"]').removeAttr('readonly');
  $('input[name="rca"]').removeAttr('readonly');
  $('input[name="regiao"]').removeAttr('readonly');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form-group'>
  <div class='col-xs-12'>
    <center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Funcionário</label></center>
    <input type='text' name='funcionario' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['funcionario']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly'>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='form-group'>
  <div class='col-xs-12'>
    <center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>RCA</label></center>
    <input type='text' name='rca' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['rca']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly'>
  </div>
</div <div class='form-group'>
<div class='col-xs-12'>
  <center>
    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Região</label></center>
  <input type='text' name='regiao' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['regiao']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly'>
</div>
</div <div class='form-group'>
<div class='col-xs-6'>
  <button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block' role='button' id='btnEditar'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>&nbsp;Editar</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dê uma conferida em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891734/setting-a-control-to-readonly-using-jquery-1-6-prop

Comment: @Gabriel então fiz do jeito que falou, pode ter sido resolvido algum erro, mais mesmo assim, ainda não faz nada quando clico no button

Comment: se voce fizer um alert('exemplo') dentro do click ele é disparado?

Comment: não, você quer ver o código completo?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues postei o código todo na resposta

Answer (score 1):

Bom tem alguns pequenos erros de sintaxe no seu código que estão afetando o funcionamento.

**Verifique o fechamento de suas `<div class='form-group'>` pois algumas ficaram sem `</div>`**

**Não utilize aspas para se referênciar ao DOM:**

Troque `$('document')` por `$(document)`

**Coloque todo seletor do input entre aspas:**

Torque `$(input[name="funcionario"])` por `$("input[name='funcionario']")`

**O nome correto da propriedade é readOnly:**
Troque `'readyonly'` por `'readonly'`

```js
$(function(){ //Onload, ao carregar 

  $(document).on('click','#btnEditar', function(){
   //Existe mais de uma forma de você remover o readonly.
   //Demonstrarei 2 formas abaixo:

     $("input[name='funcionario']").removeAttr('readonly');
     $("input[name='rca']").prop('readonly', false);
     $("input[name='regiao']").prop('readonly', false);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='form-group'>
    <div class='col-xs-12'>
    <center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Funcionário</label>         </center>
    <input type='text' name='funcionario' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['funcionario']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
    </div>
</div>

<div class='form-group'>
    <div class='col-xs-12'>
    <center>
        <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>RCA</label>
    </center>
    <input type='text' name='rca' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['rca']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class='col-xs-12'>
    <center>
       <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Região</label>             </center>
    <input type='text' name='regiao' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['regiao']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
    </div>
</div>

<div class='form-group'>
    <div class='col-xs-6'>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block' role='button' id='btnEditar'>
          <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>
          &nbsp;Editar
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tambem pode fazer assim:

```
 $('input[name="regiao"]').prop('readonly', false);
```

Comment: nada de funcionar, nenhuma das duas formas funciona...

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que o erro seja esse:

```
$('document').on('click', function() {.....}
```

Pois você está aguardando um click no documento. Para pegar o click do botão basta modificar seu código assim:

```
$("#btnEditar").on('click', function() {.....}
```

Dessa forma o evento vai disparar ao click do botão.

Comment: poderia ser, porém não funciona, postei o código em uma resposta de como ele está...